# Accessing symfony form collection prototype attributes/properties inside twig block

Tags: symfony, twig, formcollection

I am trying to setup a custom symfony form collection prototype component of a form. I am referencing the proper documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype

The form collection is setup using the following

```
        <table class="table table-bordered" data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.quoteItemDeliverables.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
        <caption>Deliverables</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Date Required</th>
        </tr>
        {% for itemDeliverable in form.quoteItemDeliverables %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form_widget(itemDeliverable.quantity) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(itemDeliverable.dateRequired) }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

The twig block that is referencing the prototype is setup using the following

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block _uniflytebundle_quoteitem_quoteItemDeliverables_entry_row %}
<tr>
    {#<td>{{ form_widget(form.quoteItemDeliverables.vars.prototype.quantity) }}</td>#}
</tr>

{{ dump(form.children["quoteItemDeliverables"]) }}
{% endblock %}
```

The dump(); is returning the following error

```
Key "quoteItemDeliverables" for array with keys "quantity, dateRequired" does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I dump(form); I get the form object displaying the children, the "quoteItemDeliverables" and the "prototype" elements

[image: dump screenshot]

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to access the various form properties? Trying to do what was done in the collection form for the prototype. Below being working form collection elements.

```
            <td>{{ form_widget(itemDeliverable.quantity) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(itemDeliverable.dateRequired) }}</td>
```

I would like the same for the prototype twig block but using something like

```
form_widget(itemDeliverable.prototype.dateRequired)
```

does not work. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort invested.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Alan. I have tried this. It also errors -                                           
 Neither the property "quantity" nor one of the methods "quantity()", "getquantity()"/"isquantity()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"

Answer (score 0):

Inside the twig block, `form` does not refer to the "global" form but to the sub form corresponding to the entry of your collection. That is why the error produced by the `dump` call indicates that the array has `quantity` and `dateRequired` keys but no `quoteItemDeliverables`.

Thus what you should have is more likely to be something like:

```
{% block _uniflytebundle_quoteitem_quoteItemDeliverables_entry_row %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.quantity) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.dateRequired}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endblock %}
```